# Diagram in TikZ (or other package)

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

I need to make a graphic in LaTeX, almost exactly like the one below but I didn't find any examples of similar diagrams.

Can anyone help me?

(I removed the text because I didn't want to infringe on anyones copyright.)

[image: diagram]

Comment: Did you search on [TeXample.net](http://texample.net)?

Comment: Maybe [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154858/how-to-create-a-leontief-gozintograph-with-tikz/154956#154956) can help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option using [`TikZ`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance=1.5cm and 1cm,
shorten >= 4pt,
shorten <= 4pt,
nodei/.style={
  text width=3cm,
  align=center
  },
nodeii/.style={
  text width=3cm,
  draw,
  dashed,
  minimum height=1.5cm,
  align=center
  },
>=latex
]
% the nodes
\node[nodei] (leftup) {Some text here\\Aditional text};
\node[nodei,below=of leftup] (leftdown) {Some text here\\Aditional text};
\node[nodei,right=5cm of leftup] (rightup) {Some text here\\Aditional text};
\node[nodei,below=of rightup] (rightdown) {Some text here\\Aditional text};
\node[nodei,below right=3cm and 1cm of leftdown] (midup) {Some text here\\Aditional text}; 
\node[nodeii,below=0.5cm of midup] (midmid) {Some text here\\Aditional text}; 
\node[nodeii,below=of midmid] (middown) {Some text here\\Aditional text}; 

\node[draw,inner sep=10pt,fit={(leftup) (leftdown)}] (left) {};
\node[draw,inner sep=10pt,fit={(midup) (middown)}] (middle) {};
\node[draw,inner sep=10pt,fit={(rightup) (rightdown)}] (right) {};

% the arrows
\draw[->] ([xshift=1cm]middown.north) -- ([xshift=1cm]middown.north|-midmid.south);
\draw[->] ([xshift=-1cm]middown.north) -- ([xshift=-1cm]middown.north|-midmid.south);
\draw[<-] (middown.north) -- node[fill=white] {some text} (middown.north|-midmid.south);

\draw[->] ([yshift=1cm]left.east) -- ([yshift=1cm]right.west|-left.east);
\draw[<-] ([yshift=-1cm]left.east) -- ([yshift=-1cm]right.west|-left.east);

\draw[->] (left.south east) -- ([xshift=25pt]middle.north west);
\draw[<-] ([xshift=-25pt]left.south east) -- (middle.north west);

\draw[->] (right.south west) -- ([xshift=-25pt]middle.north east);
\draw[<-] ([xshift=25pt]right.south west) -- (middle.north east);

% the node between the arrows
\node[nodei] at (middle.north|-left.west) {Some \\ text};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @testuserpleaseignore You're welcome! Don't forget that you can accept answers that best solved your problems by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer. In case of doubt, please see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852/3954).

Answer (score 2):

As Thorsten mentioned, http://texample.net has many great examples: [List of all tikz examples](http://texample.net/tikz/examples/all/)

I found one example here for a [large flowchart](http://texample.net/tikz/examples/consort-flowchart/).

[image]

You can probably use that as inspiration. It's done by

- defining styles for the nodes (no border, rectangle border)
- placing the nodes using a TikZ matrix
- connectiong nodes by paths with line style